# Issue with assigning sparkpoolname in synapse pipeline deployed from template

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-cli, azure-synapse

I am currently deploying our synapse workspace using az cli and json templates and after deploying, pipeline is unable to pickup the spark pool name from pipeline parameters as in the attached pic.

[image: Screenshot of pipeline and highlighted is the issue]

[image: Screenshot of pipeline parameter]

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting to Microsoft forum, came to know that this is a bug with synapse devops deployment. As a work around, I am deploying synapse notebook with powershell Az.Synapse module which will let me assign sparkpool. From this, triggering the pipeline will not give an issue.